# Am I at risk of wiping my Windows 8?

Tags: installation, 13.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I'm using a Windows 8 64 bit and I'm intending download Ubuntu 13. i downloaded the windows installer version but ubuntu wouldn't load, so I uninstalled it. So now that I'm downloading the actual thing, am I going to lose my Windows 8 os and all my other data, or will I be able to choose from both OSs whenever my computer boots up? I know this will be closed, but i just need to be positive of what I'm doing, as I don't want to lose anything.

Comment: Yes! There is a positive probability that you will make a mistake and wipe out all your data while trying to install Ubuntu. Make 3 backups in 3 different external media and verify that you can restore the the data from all 3 media before you proceed. Once you learn how to backup your data and restore it. You will be ready.

Comment: if i download ubuntu onto a usb, will that prevent any sort of risk?

Comment: The risk is not during downloading. It is during installation. You will have to change the size of existing partition(s) and may additionally need to delete a partition (if all 4 primary partitions are in use). These steps can result in mistakes. Ubuntu installation process will try to guide you for a simple dual-boot install. However, sometimes you may have to take the advanced option, where mistakes can be made.

Comment: When you install Ubuntu make sure your Windows is backed-up first.  You shouldn't lose anything if you read all the prompts carefully and think about the questions you are being asked. Instructions are [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/107450)

Comment: using usb is easier to mistake harddrive as the usb and accidently wipe the drive.